# I'm getting an index error when I use index to access my list

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, twitter

I've started using snscrape to get twitter data for my project. I'm outputting the data in a list format and using pandas to properly visualize it. since the engagement data is not constant and consistenly updates. I'm trying to use, a for loop and an if statement to compare and update it if needed but when I try to use index to access the specific properties in the list like:

like, retweet and reply count

It gives me an index error.

Script

```
#get data

import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd 

tweets_list1 = []
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
    if i > 100:
        break
    tweets_list1.append([tweet.content, tweet.id,tweet.likeCount, tweet.retweetCount, tweet.replyCount, tweet.user.username])
    print(tweets_list1)

tweets_df1 = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list1, columns=['text', 'Tweet id','LikeCount', 'RetweetCount', 'ReplyCount', 'Username'])
tweets_df1.head()

#updating engagement

tweets_list1 = []
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
    if tweet.likeCount > tweets_list1[2]:
        tweets_list1.insert(2, tweet.likeCount)
    elif i > 100:
        break
```

Error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-c679f6d5eecc> in <module>
      3 tweets_list1 = []
      4 for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
----> 5     if tweet.likeCount > tweets_list1[2]:
      6         tweets_list1.insert(2, tweet.likeCount)
      7     elif i > 100:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You have: `tweets_list1 = []`, but then access: `tweets_list1[2]`. What do you expect to find at: `tweets_list1[2]:`?

Comment: yeah you are right my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the main issue is with the reassignment of tweets_list1 in the updating engagement section.

It seems like you are assigning an empty list to variable *tweets_list1*, before performing the loop logic

```
tweets_list1 = [] # <-- Here
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
    if tweet.likeCount > tweets_list1[2]:
        tweets_list1.insert(2, tweet.likeCount)
    elif i > 100:
        break
```

Then, during the first loop, you will try to access the 3rd element of an empty list, therefore causing the error.

```
tweets_list1 = []
for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
    if tweet.likeCount > tweets_list1[2]: # <-- Here
        tweets_list1.insert(2, tweet.likeCount)
    elif i > 100:
        break
```

Comment: you are right I was creating a new list that was empty. That's why I was getting the index error.